# static variables vs structs for singletons

Tags: c, struct, static

From a software design point-of-view, when should I prefer (file scope) static variables over a struct to implement a module of which I only need a single instance of, or prefer the struct over the static variables?

A small example to illustrate (without headers for the sake of simplicity):

module_a.c

```
static int a = 1;
static int b = 2;

int module_a_add(void)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

module_b.c

```
struct s_module_b {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int module_b_add(struct s_module_b *obj)
{
    return obj->a + obj->b;
}
```

main.c

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int res;

    //v1
    res = module_a_add();

    //v2
    struct s_module_b mod = {1,2};
    res = module_b_add(&mod);

    return 0;
}
```

Going further, lets look at a bigger project: I have some utility modules which are implemented with static variables. But the more central modules, which do different stages of computations, are all implemented with structs. From those modules, some are singletons (I know that C does not know singletons, I'm just saying I only instantiate the module once), and some are not. I personally prefer the version with the static variables as it is less to type and looks overall cleaner to me. But I hesitate to rewrite the respective modules because it would end the unified style. Are there any objective advantages of one version over the other?

And there is a second problem closely related. Of those singleton modules, a single module can be provided my different implementations, decided at runtime. If I have file scope static variables in all implementations, all are allocated even only those of a single implementation are used.

Comment: How about this way? You unify all modules with struct version. And in the meantime, you also be able to use static variables for those singleton modules. E.g., in module_b.c, put two lines like this, `struct s_module_b singleton = { .a = 1, .b = 2 }; <new line> #define module_b_add_singleton()  module_b_add(&singleton)`. Then in main.c, call `module_b_add_singleton()` instead of `module_b_add(&mod)`

Answer (score 0):

The two shown versions are not comparable in the desired respect, since they substantially differ in the place of definition as well as in visibility and accessibility of `a` and `b`: In `module_a.c`, `a` and `b` are defined, initialized and inaccessible from `main.c`, while with `module_b.c`, the structure members `a` and `b` are allocated and initialized in `main.c` and passed as arguments to the function `module_b_add()`.

To present comparable versions, we'd have to change `module_a.c` to

```
int module_a_add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

(`a` and `b` passed as arguments like in `v2`), or `module_b.c` to

```
static struct s_module_b {
    int a;
    int b;
} obj = {1, 2};

int module_b_add(void)
{
    return obj.a + obj.b;
}
```

(inaccessible from `main.c` like in `v1`).